# no such file or directory on retrofit2 Call response

Tags: java, android

I want to add a file in the `RequestBody` using `retrofit2` POST. But the response is always "no such file or directory" in the call response. I don't know where is the problem.

Manidest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here is method:

```
    public static void stackoverflowGuysHelpMePls(){


        File file = new File("android.resource://myapps.me.test/drawable/myimage");
        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);     
         RequestBody requestFile =
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),file);

            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("data",file.getName(),requestFile);

            Call<JsonObject> call = apiInterface.addSound4( body);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call,
                                       Response<JsonObject> response) {
                    Log.v("xxx", "success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("xxx", ":( "+t.getMessage());
                }
            });
    }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Put this below function to get file body object

```
@NonNull
public static MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, String fileUri) {
    File file = new File(fileUri);
    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType), file);

    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```

and replace this code into your code as

```
Uri fileUrl = Uri.parse("android.resource://myapps.me.test/drawable/myimage");
MultipartBody.Part body = prepareFilePart("data",fileUrl);
```

This will work.

Comment: I have the same response ":( android.resource:/myapps.me.test/drawable/myimage.png (No such file or directory)". I tried with and without drawable and .png extension in my path.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
     if (file != null) {
       RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-
       data"),file);

       MultipartBody.Part body = 
       MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("data",file.getName(),requestFile);
      }
```

Comment: i changed MediaType.parse("image/*"),file) for MediaType.parse("multipart/form-
       data"),file). But don't works bro.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the comments I think the error is related to not being able to load the resource, a stacktrace could help more on this question.

Instead of using a `File` object, try passing on the `ByteArray`.

Try this: (kotlin)

```
    val resourceAsBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.test)
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    resourceAsBitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), stream.toByteArray())
```

In java it would be something like this:

```
Bitmap resourceAsBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.test); // here use R.drawable.your_resource
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
if (resourceAsBitmap != null) {
    resourceAsBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream.toByteArray());
}
```

probably with some possible IOExceptions here or there.